# How to get the active layer and use it as input layer for dissolve in PyQis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

This is my Script:

```py
from qgis import processing

inlayDir = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\Trial PyQGIS\cdc_1stfill.shp'

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve",
                             {'INPUT': 'inlayDir', 
                              'FIELD':[],
                              'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
                              
                              
#iface.addVectorLayer(output['OUTPUT'], 'Dissolved', 'ogr')
```

I want make my input layer as any layer I select.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: (For your current code to work you need to use `inlayDir` as input not `'inlayDir'`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `activeLayer` method of the `iface` object.

```
from qgis import processing

inlayDir = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\Trial PyQGIS\cdc_1stfill.shp'

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve", {'INPUT': iface.activeLayer(), 'FIELD':[], 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

#iface.addVectorLayer(output['OUTPUT'], 'Dissolved', 'ogr')
```